# Not sure what this error refers to, in beanplot

Tags: r, data-visualization

When I attempt to create a Beanplot for some data I get the following error

```
library(beanplot)
beanplot(error ~ rates, data = result[result$stream=="Speelyai", ],
col=c("orange", "black", "white", "red"), border ="pink",
what=c(0,1,1,1), maxstripline=.20)


Error in bw.SJ(x, method = "dpi") : sample is too sparse to find TD
```

Here is an attempt at using `dput` to provide a reproducible example

```
 dput(head(result, 20))
 structure(list(stream = c("Brooks", "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", 
 "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", 
 "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", 
 "Siouxon", "Speelyai", "Brooks", "Siouxon"), n = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 
 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9), rates = c(3, 
 3, 3, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 17, 
 17, 17, 19.5, 19.5), means = c(0.962915209069, 0.583192916943, 
 0.619923506082, 0.972270732503, 0.586503057099, 0.6118633820775, 
 0.9637475111, 0.580441970844, 0.5959238270885, 0.948657459436, 
 0.5846854247605, 0.559714620214, 0.954776205607, 0.582733153046333, 
 0.588721324855, 0.927079783491, 0.589401183924667, 0.584910716913, 
 0.9468615412695, 0.578929242163667), column = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
 "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
 "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
 "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
 "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
 "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
 "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
 "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
 "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
 "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
 "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
 "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
 "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
 "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
 "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", 
 "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
 "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", 
 "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
 "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", 
 "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
 "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", 
 "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", 
 "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", 
 "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", 
 "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", 
 "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", 
 "251", "252", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", 
 "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", 
 "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", 
 "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", 
 "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", 
 "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", 
 "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", 
 "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", 
 "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", 
 "332", "333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", 
 "341", "342", "343", "344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", 
 "350", "351", "352", "353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", 
 "359", "360", "361", "362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", 
 "368", "369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", 
 "377", "378", "379", "380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", 
 "386", "387", "388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", 
 "395", "396", "397", "398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", 
 "404", "405", "406", "407", "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", 
 "413", "414", "415", "416", "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", 
 "422", "423", "424", "425", "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", 
 "431", "432", "433", "434", "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", 
 "440", "441", "442", "443", "444", "445", "446", "447", "448", 
 "449", "450", "451", "452", "453", "454", "455", "456", "457", 
 "458", "459", "460", "461", "462", "463", "464", "465", "466", 
 "467", "468", "469", "470", "471", "472", "473", "474", "475", 
 "476", "477", "478", "479", "480", "481", "482", "483", "484", 
 "485", "486", "487", "488", "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", 
 "494", "495", "496", "497", "498", "499", "500", "501", "502", 
 "503", "504", "505", "506", "507", "508", "509", "510", "511", 
 "512", "513", "514", "515", "516", "517", "518", "519", "520", 
 "521", "522", "523", "524", "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", 
 "530", "531", "532", "533", "534", "535", "536", "537", "538", 
 "539", "540", "541", "542", "543", "544", "545", "546", "547", 
 "548", "549", "550", "551", "552", "553", "554", "555", "556", 
 "557", "558", "559", "560", "561", "562", "563", "564", "565", 
 "566", "567", "568", "569", "570", "571", "572", "573", "574", 
 "575", "576", "577", "578", "579", "580", "581", "582", "583", 
 "584", "585", "586", "587", "588", "589", "590", "591", "592", 
 "593", "594", "595", "596", "597", "598", "599", "600", "601", 
 "602", "603", "604", "605", "606", "607", "608", "609", "610", 
 "611", "612", "613", "614", "615", "616", "617", "618", "619", 
 "620", "621", "622", "623", "624", "625", "626", "627", "628", 
 "629", "630", "631", "632", "633", "634", "635", "636", "637", 
 "638", "639", "640", "641", "642", "643", "644", "645", "646", 
 "647", "648", "649", "650", "651", "652", "653", "654", "655", 
 "656", "657", "658", "659", "660", "661", "662", "663", "664", 
 "665", "666", "667", "668", "669", "670", "671", "672", "673", 
 "674", "675", "676", "677", "678", "679", "680", "681", "682", 
 "683", "684", "685", "686", "687", "688", "689", "690", "691", 
 "692", "693", "694", "695", "696", "697", "698", "699", "700", 
 "701", "702", "703", "704", "705", "706", "707", "708", "709", 
 "710", "711", "712", "713", "714", "715", "716", "717", "718", 
 "719", "720", "721", "722", "723", "724", "725", "726", "727", 
 "728", "729", "730", "731", "732", "733", "734", "735", "736", 
 "737", "738", "739", "740", "741", "742", "743", "744", "745", 
 "746", "747", "748", "749", "750", "751", "752", "753", "754", 
 "755", "756", "757", "758", "759", "760", "761", "762", "763", 
 "764", "765", "766", "767", "768", "769", "770", "771", "772", 
 "773", "774", "775", "776", "777", "778", "779", "780", "781", 
 "782", "783", "784", "785", "786", "787", "788", "789", "790", 
 "791", "792", "793", "794", "795", "796", "797", "798", "799", 
 "800", "801", "802", "803", "804", "805", "806", "807", "808", 
 "809", "810", "811", "812", "813", "814", "815", "816", "817", 
 "818", "819", "820", "821", "822", "823", "824", "825", "826", 
 "827", "828", "829", "830", "831", "832", "833", "834", "835", 
 "836", "837", "838", "839", "840", "841", "842", "843", "844", 
 "845", "846", "847", "848", "849", "850", "851", "852", "853", 
 "854", "855", "856", "857", "858", "859", "860", "861", "862", 
 "863", "864", "865", "866", "867", "868", "869", "870", "871", 
 "872", "873", "874", "875", "876", "877", "878", "879", "880", 
 "881", "882", "883", "884", "885", "886", "887", "888", "889", 
 "890", "891", "892", "893", "894", "895", "896", "897", "898", 
 "899", "900", "901", "902", "903", "904", "905", "906", "907", 
 "908", "909", "910", "911", "912", "913", "914", "915", "916", 
 "917", "918", "919", "920", "921", "922", "923", "924", "925", 
 "926", "927", "928", "929", "930", "931", "932", "933", "934", 
 "935", "936", "937", "938", "939", "940", "941", "942", "943", 
 "944", "945", "946", "947", "948", "949", "950", "951", "952", 
 "953", "954", "955", "956", "957", "958", "959", "960", "961", 
 "962", "963", "964", "965", "966", "967", "968", "969", "970", 
 "971", "972", "973", "974", "975", "976", "977", "978", "979", 
 "980", "981", "982", "983", "984", "985", "986", "987", "988", 
 "989", "990", "991", "992", "993", "994", "995", "996", "997", 
 "998", "999", "1000"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.427070064, 
 0.905037358, 0.085540211, 1.43338843, 0.50574543, 0.3225239615, 
 0.889842105, 0.475018001, 0.150794906, 1.324221046, 0.3947968405, 
 0.370059413, 1.763186222, 0.794329673, 0.366688618666667, 0.288093907, 
 0.599490175666667, 1.31257167275, 1.147111171, 0.587266637333333
 ), truevalue = c(0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402, 0.944062036, 
 0.585852702, 0.583984402, 0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402, 
 0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402, 0.944062036, 0.585852702, 
 0.583984402, 0.944062036, 0.585852702, 0.583984402, 0.944062036, 
 0.585852702), error = c(-0.516991972, 0.319184656, -0.498444191, 
 0.489326394, -0.0801072719999999, -0.2614604405, -0.054219931, 
 -0.110834701, -0.433189496, 0.38015901, -0.1910558615, -0.213924989, 
 0.819124186, 0.208476971, -0.217295783333333, -0.655968129,               0.0136374736666667, 
 0.72858727075, 0.203049135, 0.00141393533333334)), .Names = c("stream", 
 "n", "rates", "means", "column", "value", "truevalue", "error"
 ), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is very hard to help you without a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example. Please provide a `dput` of your data that reproduces that error.

Comment: @SabDeM How do I offer a reproducible example? I am not sure how to "generate" this data, as it is not generated, but collected, and summarized from field observations.

Comment: As I've said, I think that would be necessary a `dput(head(you_data, 20))` of your data. Very important: be sure that code reproduce the error otherwise if we cannot reproduce it we cannot solve (most likely).

Comment: @SabDeM Ok, there is the reproducible example

Comment: Now that I have the data, your code works well for me, it produces a pretty plot. I use the  `packageVersion("beanplot") [1] ‘1.2’`.

Comment: I tried to replicate with a data set with an underrepresented category but didn't get an error: `library(beanplot);  dd <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),f=factor(rep(1:2,c(999,1))));
 beanplot(x~f,data=dd,what=c(0,1,1,1))` works fine for me (also version 1.2)

Comment: Interesting. Can you please try again and set `stream=="Siouxon"`

Comment: This [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/beanplot-Error-sample-is-too-sparse-to-find-TD-td4291739.html) was also helpful to some extent. The density estimation procedure can produce that kind of error you are referring to.

Comment: @S.A. the link does not work :-(

Comment: @Exploring it's still working here:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300688.html